# ErrorException in myth auth login

Tags: javascript, authentication, codeigniter-4

I'm using myth auth library to my login form. When I ran the login it said:

`ErrorException Undefined variable: config`

here are the code for my view l

```
<?= $this->extend($config->viewLayout); ?>
<form action="<?= base_url(route_to('login')) ?>" method="post">
                                        <?= csrf_field() ?>
 <?php if ($config->validFields === ['email']): ?>
    <div class="form-group">
       
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user <?php if(session('errors.login')) : ?>is- 
     invalid<?php endif ?>" name="login"  placeholder="<?=lang('Auth.email')?>">
                                                
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
   <?= session('errors.login') ?>
  </div>
  </div>

<?php else: ?>
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control <?php if(session('errors.login')) : ?>is-invalid<?php endif ? 
       >" name="login" placeholder="<?=lang('Auth.emailOrUsername')?>">
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    <?= session('errors.login') ?>
  </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: where is your `$config` variable defined?

Comment: here are the source of config but i didnt know where its from <?= $this->extend($config->viewLayout); ?>

Comment: How did you install the auth library?

Comment: using vs code terminal, composer require myth/auth

Answer (score 0):

In my case, once logged on, it redirected back to the login page with the error above. To solve the issue, I create a public constructor which contains the variable config and pass the variable to the login view.

Public constructor method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->session = service('session');
    $this->config = config('Auth');
    $this->auth = service('authentication');
}
```

Public index method:

```
{
    $data = [
        'config' => $this->config
    ];
    return view('/forms/login', $data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

myth\auth\src\convig\auth line 50

```
public $validFields = [
    'username', 'email'
];
```

Don't remove 'email'.

Comment: If you add some explanation re. why this code works, your answer would be vastly improved